# Escape character needed on *?

Tags: java, escaping

I am trying to search an ASCII file for *CELL_OPEN and *CELL_CLOSE with the * being itself (i.e. not an operator)

I have this code:

```
do {
  importstring++; 
  numberline = ImportFiles.importarray.get(importstring);
} while (!numberline.startsWith("*CELL_CLOSE"))
```

This is identical other than an extra method for *CELL_OPEN. 
When I run this, it doesn't find *CELL_OPEN or *CELL_CLOSE. As such I get an index out of bounds error.
Do I need an escape for * to be taken literally? I suspect so. If I do, what is the correct syntax for it? 
* does not work. \* has the same result as no escape.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I need an escape for * to be taken literally?

No. Unless a string is being used to create a regular expression (and it isn't, with `startsWith`), the `"*"` character is not special.

Your problem lies elsewhere. Presumably it's that `numberline` never actually starts with `*CELL_CLOSE`. (Perhaps there's some whitespace?) Your best bet for figuring out the actual problem is to walk through with a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need an escape character since you are matching a string and not a reg exp.
The problem seems to be in:

```
importstring++; 
numberline = ImportFiles.importarray.get(importstring);
```

Basically your importstring gets bigger then the size of the array you get from ImportFiles.importarray

I think you need another stopping condition in the lines of

```
}while (importstring < ImportFiles.importarray.size && !numberline.startsWith("*CELL_CLOSE"))
```